# Kotlin app using camera does not return picture if camera is never launched before

Tags: kotlin, camera

I've stuck for a while with annoying issue with emulator's camera in my app. (The same is repro on a real device)

The camera is used from a dialog fragment to take a picture that later will be uploaded to remote host.

```
private val cameraPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
) { isGranted ->
    if (isGranted) {
        makeImageWithCamera()
    } else {
        dismiss()
    }
}

private val cameraLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()
) { isSuccess ->
    if (isSuccess) {
        path?.let { path ->
            viewModel.setPhoto(path = path)
        }
    }
    dismiss()
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    subscribeFlow(viewModel.action) { dismiss() }
    with(binding) {
        buttonCamera.setOnClickListener { useCamera() }
        buttonCancel.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }
    }
}

private fun useCamera() {
     val isGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), PERM_CAMERA) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
     if (!isGranted) {
         cameraPermissionLauncher.launch(PERM_CAMERA)
     } else {
         makeImageWithCamera()
     }
}

private fun makeImageWithCamera() {
    try {
        val photoFileName = "photo${id}"
        val photosDir = requireContext()
            .getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val photoFile = File.createTempFile(photoFileName, ".jpg", photosDir)
        val photoUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            requireContext(),
            "app.provider",
            photoFile
        )
        path = photoFile.absolutePath
        cameraLauncher.launch(photoUri)
    } catch (err : IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, err.stackTraceToString())
    }
}
```

The issue happens only in situation when camera itself is never launched on a device:

1. Inside my app I press camera button
2. Receive a request for camera usage permission from my app and accept it.
3. Camera app is starting and requests its own permission to access geolocation (it wants to add location-based tags to photos) - at this point it is irrelevant wether to accept or deny it.
4. Camera enters the scene. Now if I press shot button it makes a photo and stays in the scene allowing to make infinite amount of photos, as if I've launched Camera app in regular way.
5. If I use back button to return to my app - nothing have change at all, dialog is just dismisses.

[image: my app permission request]
[image: camera app permission request]

[image: first launch of camera app]
[image: as if it launched independently]
[image: problem state in which it allows to make photos indefinitely]

If I launch the same second time, or just launch Camera app itself and accept/deny permissions request from it, all is fixed. Camera takes exactly one shot and allows me to accept it, after that it comes back to my app and processes received photo.

[image: good state in which it allows to accept taken photo and return]

So while for the user experience this behaviour can be just annoying, it with a high probability makes the Firebase robotests to fail on this point.
What could be the possible root of a problem?

Comment: What is `PERM_CAMERA`?

Comment: const val PERM_CAMERA: String = Manifest.permission.CAMERA